# Find minimum GCD of a pair of elements in an array

Tags: primes, prime-factoring, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor, modular-arithmetic

> Given an array of elements, I have to find the **MINIMUM GCD** possible
>   between any two pairs of the array in least time complexity.

*Example*

Input

```
arr=[7,3,14,9,6]
```

Constraint

```
N= 10^ 5
```

Output

```
1
```

Explanation

```
min gcd can be of pair(7,3)
```

My naive solution- O(n^2) bad naive brute force

```
int ans=INT_MAX;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
        int g= __gcd(arr[i],arr[j]);
        ans=min(ans,g);
    }
}

return ans;
```

**Can you suggest a better method of least time complexity?**

Comment: To answer the question more information must be known about the sizes of the integers in the list and their distribution. For example, if the list really is always 100,000 long and the integers are randomly generated then the gcd in your algorithm should reach 1 very quickly and you can simply exit the program at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in time O(n + h log h), where h is the maximum number in the array. Let's solve a harder problem: for each x <= h, count the number d[x] of unordered pairs (i, j) such that 0 <= i, j < n and GCD(a[i], a[j]) = x. To solve your problem, just find the smallest x such that d[x] is positive. Also note that counting ordered pairs (i, j) with i = j does not influence the solution. The solution uses Mobius inversion - basically a variation of Inclusion-Exclusion for divisors of integers.

Mobius inversion can be used to solve the following problem: you need to find an array y, but you're given an array z such that z[k] = y[k] + y[2*k] + y[3*k] + .... Surprisingly, it works in-place and it's just three lines of code!

This is exactly what we need, first we'll find the number of ordered pairs (i, j) such that d[x] **divides** GCD(a[i], a[j]), but we need the number of ordered pairs (i, j) such that d[x] **is** GCD(a[i], a[j]).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int main() {
    int n, h = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int& x : a) {
        cin >> x;
        h = max(h, x);
    }
    h++;
    vector<ll> c(h), d(h);
    for (int x : a)
        c[x]++;

    for (int i=1; i<h; i++)
        for (int j=i; j<h; j+=i)
            d[i] += c[j];

    // now, d[x] = no. of indices i such that x divides a[i] 

    for (int i=1; i<h; i++)
        d[i] *= d[i];

    // now, d[x] = number of pairs of indices (i, j) such that
    // x divides a[i] and a[j] (just square the previous d)
    // equiv. x divides GCD(a[i], a[j])

    // apply Mobius inversion to get proper values of d
    for (int i=h-1; i>0; i--)
        for (int j=2*i; j<h; j+=i)
            d[i] -= d[j];

    for (int i=1; i<h; i++) {
        if (d[i]) {
            cout << i << '\n';
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```